# Control what JS is executed in an Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

Is it possible to control which JS is executed in an Android WebView on a fine-grained level?
As far as I can tell it is only possible to enable/disable JS in the WebView globally and add JS Interfaces.

But what about blocking just certain APIs in a WebView? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you can do:

1. Prevent certain JS source files from being loaded by overriding `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest`.
2. After loading the page, override the functions / object you want to disable with empty functions / nulls / whatever.

Comment: Thanks, overriding the JS functions was the correct thing for my use case